# How to subtract the value from previous value

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions, oracle21c

I have a table like this:

| DT | PRIN | INT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2023 | 100000 | 1100 |
| 01-02-2023 | 100000 | 1200 |
| 01-03-2023 | 100000 | 1500 |
| 01-04-2023 | 100000 | 2300 |

I need to subtract `INT` column from `PRIN` and get the subtracted amount in first row.
On second and following rows I need to also subtract `INT` values from all preceding rows.

The result should look like this:

| DT | PRIN | INT | BAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2023 | 100000 | 1100 | 98900 |
| 01-02-2023 | 100000 | 1200 | 97700 |
| 01-03-2023 | 100000 | 1500 | 96200 |
| 01-04-2023 | 100000 | 2300 | 93900 |

I have tried using `LEAD` and `LAG` functionality but cannot get subtraction correctly and this should be done in SQL.

Here is the script:

```sql
create table tbl9 ( dt date, prin varchar2(20), int varchar2(20));
insert into tbl9 values(to_date('01-01-2023','dd-mm-yyyy'),100000, 1100);
insert into tbl9 values(to_date('01-02-2023','dd-mm-yyyy'),100000, 1200);
insert into tbl9 values(to_date('01-03-2023','dd-mm-yyyy'),100000, 1500);
insert into tbl9 values(to_date('01-04-2023','dd-mm-yyyy'),100000, 2300);
commit;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Window Function `SUM()` for that

```
SELECT dt,prin, int, prin - SUM(int) OVER(PARTITION BY prin ORDER BY dt) bal
FROM tbl9
```

| DT | PRIN | INT | BAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-JAN-23 | 100000 | 1100 | 98900 |
| 01-FEB-23 | 100000 | 1200 | 97700 |
| 01-MAR-23 | 100000 | 1500 | 96200 |
| 01-APR-23 | 100000 | 2300 | 93900 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tWGAAkvt)

Comment: This only gets the answer the OP expects if the `PRIN` column is the same for all rows. If the OP wants to "subtract `INT` column from `PRIN` and get the subtracted amount in first row. On second and following rows [...] subtract `INT` values from all preceding rows." then you do not want to use `PRIN` from the current row, you want to always use the `PRIN` value of the first row.

Comment: you are right, but the table seem more like an extact from another bigger table, that is why prin is always the same numbe

Comment: If we are not using order by it will give total sum with in partition . I am not understanding how the order by is giving running total . It is just for ordering right ???

Comment: a window function needs a order your date does give us such, so there is no poblem, your data seems a bit off, so i think that you selected it from some larger table

Comment: @Erik The `order by` comes with an [implicit frame clause `between unbounded preceding and current row`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlrf/Analytic-Functions.html#GUID-527832F7-63C0-4445-8C16-307FA5084056__GUID-C08BA9CF-6BCD-4D31-A1EA-DCEF7172A499) that makes this a cumulative sum. [See the example in the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlrf/SUM.html#GUID-5610BE2C-CFE5-446F-A1F7-B924B5663220__GUID-20E8E856-CAC7-4441-83D2-5C3DF2CD38EF)

Answer (score 0):

If `PRIN` is the same in every row then use @nbk's answer.

To answer the question:

> I need to subtract `INT` column from `PRIN` and get the subtracted amount in first row.
> On second and following rows I need to also subtract `INT` values from all preceding rows.

You need to always ensure that the cumulative sum is subtracted from the `PRIN` value in the first row (rather than the `PRIN` value from the current row).

You can either use the `FIRST_VALUE` and `SUM` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT dt,
       prin,
       int,
       FIRST_VALUE(prin) OVER (ORDER BY dt)
         - SUM(int) OVER (ORDER BY dt) AS bal
FROM   tbl9;
```

Or a `MODEL` clause:

```sql
SELECT dt,
       prin,
       int,
       bal
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROWNUM AS rn
  FROM   (SELECT * FROM tbl9 ORDER BY dt) t
)
MODEL
  DIMENSION BY (rn)
  MEASURES (dt, prin, int, 0 AS bal)  
  RULES (
    bal[1]    = prin[1] - int[1],
    bal[rn>1] = prin[CV(rn) - 1] - int[CV(rn)]
  )
```

Which, for the sample data, both output:

| DT | PRIN | INT | BAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 100000 | 1100 | 98900 |
| 2023-02-01 00:00:00 | 100000 | 1200 | 98800 |
| 2023-03-01 00:00:00 | 100000 | 1500 | 98500 |
| 2023-04-01 00:00:00 | 100000 | 2300 | 97700 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Z7EEuZ26)